# Is it possible to check if flash message exists in javascript (rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using a custom signup modal on my homepage (with devise), and I'm using flash to store the errors and show them on the custom signup modal. What I want to know is whether I can check whether there are any messages in flash using javascript, and if so, I can have the modal automatically open when redirecting to the homepage. Thus essentially I need javascript that can do the following:

```
Are there messages stored using flash? 
If so, open modal when homepage loads.
```

I can already open the modal when the homepage loads using js, but I can't work out how to check if there are messages in flash. Is it possible to access the flash and check whether there are any errors stored using js? Thanks!

EDIT:

So I'm completely new to AJAX, but I followed this: http://ashleyangell.com/2010/10/handling-rails-flash-message-with-ajax-requests/

I added the following to my application controller:

```
after_filter :flash_headers
def flash_headers
  return unless request.xhr?
  response.headers['x-flash'] = flash[:error]  unless flash[:error].blank?
  response.headers['x-flash'] = flash[:notice]  unless flash[:notice].blank?
  response.headers['x-flash'] = flash[:warning]  unless flash[:warning].blank?
  # Stops the flash appearing when you next refresh the page
  flash.discard
end
```

and I have the following javascript:

```
$(document).load(function(){
$.ajax({ 
var flash = response.getHeader('x-flash');
if (flash) alert(flash);
     });
});
```

Now I'm getting an "Unexpected Identifier" issue on the line below, and the alert does not show when there is a flash notice present.

```
var flash = response.getHeader('x-flash');
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: make ajax request for that. Open modal based on response

Comment: what would that look like?

Comment: Not hard to do google search for it. Won't have any problem finding tutorials gems etc

Comment: why use ajax not plain javascript? also I still can't work out how you treat flash as a js/ajax variable...

Comment: javscript runs in browser, your flash is on server. ajax is done by javascript making request to server and server responding with data

Comment: @chris AJAX *is* plain JavaScript.

Comment: hmm I've added what I tried, but it seems that ajax doesn't recognize the flash headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is wrong.

The ["flash" is a session cookie](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) which is created through the invocation of an action. Your theory that you can "check for flash messages" won't work. They will only be delivered in the response to a request:

> The flash is a special part of the session which is cleared with each request. This means that values stored there will only be available in the next request, which is useful for passing error messages etc.

This means you need to send your modal's form request via ajax in order to parse the returned data (regardless of whether the `x-flash` headers are present or not):

```
#modal
<%= form_tag ... remote: true do %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:success", "#new_user_form", function(data, status, xhr) {
    var flash = xhr.getHeader('x-flash');
    if (flash) alert(flash);
});
```

To understand this properly, you should read up about the [`stateless` properties of HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol#Examples):

> An example of a stateless protocol is HTTP, meaning that each request message can be understood in isolation.

---

The big thing you'll need is [`flash.now`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-now):

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    after_filter :flash_headers, if: Proc.new {|c| c.request.xhr? }

    private 

    def flash_headers
       types = %i(error notice warning)
       types.each do |type|
          response.headers['x-flash'] = flash.now.send(type) unless flash.now[type].blank?
       end
   end
end
```

`flash.now` sets the flash to be present for *that* request (not as part of a new request as default). This will allow you to send the value back through your ajax response (which, to `HTTP`, is the same request).

Remember to use `flash.now` when setting the message in your "action" controller:

```
#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      flash.now[:notice] = "Success"
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using jQuery to make the AJAX call. I think you need some JS that looks like this

```
$(document).load(function(){
  $.ajax('/url/of/action')
    .done(function(data, textStatus, request){
      var flash = request.getResponseHeader('x-flash');
      if (flash) alert(flash);
     });
});
```

That will call the `/url/of/action` and when it completes look at the headers for the `x-flash` header.

Comment: hmm I couldn't get that to work either. I'm not trying to call another url, I just want the headers from the original url that created the document

Comment: @chris you'll have to figure out what's calling the original url and JS there. There's no way to get at the headers except through the original request.